# Could not create procedure Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@TableName"

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DropMasks]
@TableName nvarchar(127)='',
@FieldName nvarchar(127)='',
@MaskFunction nvarchar(127)=''
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @ATableName nvarchar(127)=''
    declare @AFieldName nvarchar(127)=''
    declare @AMaskFunction nvarchar(127)=''
    declare @SqlStr nvarchar(max)=''
    DECLARE crs CURSOR Read_Only Fast_Forward FOR
        SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
            TableName=tbl.name,
            ColumnName=c.name,
            c.masking_function
        FROM 
            sys.masked_columns AS c inner join 
            sys.tables AS tbl ON c.object_id = tbl.object_id
        WHERE 
            is_masked=1 and 
            tbl.name like '%'+@TableName+'%' and 
            c.name like '%'+@FieldName+'%' and 
            c.masking_function like '%'+@MaskFunction+'%'
    Open crs
    Fetch Next From crs INTO @ATableName,@AFieldName,@AMaskFunction
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        set @SqlStr = @SqlStr + 
                    ' ALTER TABLE ' + @ATableName +
                    ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @AFieldName + 
                    ' DROP MASKED ' 
        Fetch Next From crs INTO @ATableName,@AFieldName,@AMaskFunction
    END
    CLOSE crs
    DEALLOCATE crs
    if @SqlStr <> ''
        exec(@SqlStr)
END;
```

I cannot see the invalid syntax or the missing declaration.

The error is;

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 28 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'PROCEDURE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 28 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'PROCEDURE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 28 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'PROCEDURE'.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 45 Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@TableName".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 45 Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@TableName".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 45 Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@TableName".
>
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 27]
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 27]
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.
>
> Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   sp_describe_parameter_encryption, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 27]
>   Statement(s) could not be prepared.

Comment: What is the SQL version you are using?

Comment: version 14.0.3038.14

Comment: try separating the procedure code with go

Comment: If your parameters are intended to be table/column/function names, why on earth would you pick `nvarchar(127)` as the type/size? [`sysname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms191240(v=sql.100)#sysname), the actual data type used for such names is the same as `nvarchar(128)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i forgot to switch always encrypted off when i connect.

thanks to

[Cannot add a stored procedure to database due to encryption message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925304/cannot-add-a-stored-procedure-to-database-due-to-encryption-message)

now works just fine.