# SQL Server error: metadata for parameter '@p[guid]' in statement or procedure '.....' is missing

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I suddenly started receiving the above error yesterday when recompiling a stored procedure that I have recompiled many times in the recent past without any problem.

The full error message is very long and starts with:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
> Must declare the scalar variable "@Force".
> ...

etc. (lots more like this - then the error message above appears with a large chunk of my SP definition in the middle of it.

At first I assumed my database had been corrupted (because indeed this only started appearing after I'd been firefighting a very large stuck transaction which was taking forever to rollback). However doing a repair with DBCC didn't reveal any problems and the issue remained. I then created a new database from scratch and used the RedGate tools to rebuild the objects, and reloaded all the data: same problem. It seems to relate to "ALWAYS ENCRYPTED" columns - but I have never used those in this (or any other) database - and a search of `sys.columns` etc. reveals that there are no ALWAYS ENCRYPTED columns.

I then figured it may be related to the update of SSMS from 18.5 to 18.5.1 - since the database itself seems otherwise fine but it just won't compile this stored procedure. But uninstalling 18.5.1 and rolling back to 18.4 didn't help.

I finally managed to work around by changing this line...

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX), @default NVARCHAR(250) = '', @fields NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

..to...

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX), @default NVARCHAR(250), @fields NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @default = ''
```

...which is consistent with it having "something to do with" ALWAYS ENCRYPTED (i.e. don't try to declare and set the variable in one statement). But ALWAYS ENCRYPTED isn't on - and in any case these are just internal variables.

I hope that anyone encountering this problem will find the workaround above helpful - but can anyone offer any insight as to what on earth is going on here and what else might have triggered it?

Many thanks,

Charles

Comment: Check the SSMS setting `Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted` to make sure it's turned off under Tools-->Options-->Query Execution-->SQL Server-->Advanced-->Enable Parameterization for Always Encrypted per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925304/cannot-add-a-stored-procedure-to-database-due-to-encryption-message).

Comment: Thanks Dan - the setting was indeed turned on, so I have turned it off. That stopped the crazy error message - but it did trigger a popup which said "you have enabled always encrypted for this query" and invited me to put the setting back on again.

I don't know how it got set in the first place, or how I have "enabled always encrypted for the query".  Microsoft moves in mysterious ways sometimes.